# Integrating XForms and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, web-applications, xforms

I was wondering if anyone here has any experience with integrating AngularJS and XForms.

We are thinking about migrating to AngularJS from GWT and we have a workflow where we retrieve XForms from the server and use them to generate the search form with all the necessary functionality (display, validation, submission...)

Is that functionality possible with AngularJs and XForms?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? How did you proceed?